# Java concurrency with a Map of Lists

Tags: java, concurrency

I have a java class that is accessed by a lot of threads at once and want to make sure it is thread safe.  The class has one private field, which is a Map of Strings to Lists of Strings.  I've implemented the Map as a ConcurrentHashMap to ensure gets and puts are thread safe:

```
public class ListStore {

  private Map<String, List<String>> innerListStore;

  public ListStore() {
    innerListStore = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, List<String>>();
  }
  ...
}
```

So given that gets and puts to the Map are thread safe, my concern is with the lists that are stored in the Map.  For instance, consider the following method that checks if a given entry exists in a given list in the store (I've omitted error checking for brevity):

```
public boolean listEntryExists(String listName, String listEntry) {

  List<String> listToSearch = innerListStore.get(listName);

  for (String entryName : listToSearch) {
    if(entryName.equals(listEntry)) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

It would seem that I need to synchronize the entire contents of this method because if another method changed the contents of the list at innerListStore.get(listName) while this method is iterating over it, a ConcurrentModificationException would be thrown.

Is that correct and if so, do I synchronize on innerListStore or would synchronizing on the local listToSearch variable work?

UPDATE: Thanks for the responses.  It sounds like I can synchronize on the list itself. For more information, here is the add() method, which can be running at the same time the listEntryExists() method is running in another thread:

```
public void add(String listName, String entryName) {

  List<String> addTo = innerListStore.get(listName);
  if (addTo == null) {
    addTo = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
    List<String> added = innerListStore.putIfAbsent(listName, addTo);
    if (added != null) {
      addTo = added;
    }
  }

  addTo.add(entryName);
}
```

If this is the only method that modifies the underlying lists stored in the map and no public methods return references to the map or entries in the map, can I synchronize iteration on the lists themselves and is this implementation of add() sufficient?

Comment: your `add()` implementation is broken.  you need to handle the results of `putIfAbsent()` correctly (otherwise you may add to the wrong list).

Comment: @jtahlborn Are you saying I need to call add() on the the List that  putIfAbsent() returns? If so, I disagree. putIfAbsent() returns whatever was **previously** associated with that key, which would be the wrong list. Right?

Comment: please re-read the documentation on the `putIfAbsent()` method (note the name of the method for that matter).

Comment: I think I see what you mean now and have edited the add().  Is that the correct way to handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could synchronize on just listToSearch, there's no reason to lock the entire map any time anyone is using just one entry.

Just remember though, that you need to synchronize on the list everywhere it is modified!  Synchronizing the iterator doesn't automagically block other people from doing an add() or whatnot if you passed out to them references to the unsynchronized list.

It would be safest to just store synchronized lists in the Map and then lock on them when you iterate, and also document when you return a reference to the list that the user must sycnhronize on it if they iterate.  Synchronization is pretty cheap in modern JVMs when no actual contention is happening.  Of course if you never let a reference to one of the lists escape your class, you can handle it internally with a finer comb.

Alternately you can use a threadsafe list such as CopyOnWriteArrayList that uses snapshot iterators.  What kind of point in time consistency you need is a design decision we can't make for you.  The [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) also includes a helpful discussion of performance characteristics.

Comment: +1 for the reminder that synchronizing the iterator in `listEntryExists` doesn't block modifications in other methods.

Comment: Sorry Affe, that was me, on a general war against synchronization. Having re-read the answer today it is perfectly sensible and doesn't deserve a down-vote. You are right that uncontended synchronization is cheap, but contended synchronization is not. The problem the locked solution has is that as the lists get larger the critical section gets larger and there is more likelihood of contention. You though step around that with the suggestion of the copy-on-write structure. Apologies, but SE won't let me remove the down-vote now.

Comment: No harm, I just like to ask since if I did say something that's wrong I want to learn about it :)

Answer (score 2):

You can synchronize on listToSearch ("synchronized(listToSearch) {...}"). Make sure that there is no race condition creating the lists (use innerListStore.putIfAbsent to create them).

Answer (score 1):

> It would seem that I need to synchronize the entire contents of this method because if another method changed the contents of the list at innerListStore.get(listName) while this method is iterating over it, a ConcurrentModificationException would be thrown.

Are other threads accessing the List itself, or only though operations exposed by `ListStore`?

Will operations invoked by other threads result in the contents of the a List stored in the Map being changed? Or will entries only be added/removed from the Map?

You would only need to synchronize access to the List stored within the Map if different threads can result in changes to the same List instances. If the threads are only allowed to add/remove List instances from the Map (i.e. change the structure of the Map), then synchronization is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If the Map is already thread safe, then I think syncronizing the listToSearch should work. Im not 100% but I think it should work

```
synchronized(listToSearch)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if the lists stored in the map are of the type that don't throw CME ([CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) for example) you can iterate at will

this can introduce some races though if you're not careful

Answer (score 0):

You could use another abstraction from [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#synchronizedListMultimap%28com.google.common.collect.ListMultimap%29)

Note that this will synchronize on the whole map, so it might be not that useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't provided any client for the map of lists apart from the `boolean listEntryExists(String listName, String listEntry)` method, I wonder why you are storing lists at all? This structure seems to be more naturally a `Map<String, Set<String>>` and the `listEntryExists` should use the `contains` method (available on `List` as well, but O(n) to the size of the list):

```
public boolean listEntryExists(String name, String entry) {
  SetString> set = map.get(name);
  return (set == null) ? false : set.contains(entry;
}
```

Now, the contains call can encapsulate whatever internal concurrency protocol you want it to.

For the `add` you can either use a synchronized wrapper (simple, but maybe slow) or if writes are infrequent compared to reads, utilise `ConcurrentMap.replace` to implement your own copy-on-write strategy. For instance, using Guava `ImmutableSet`:

```
public boolean add(String name, String entry) {
  while(true) {
    SetString> set = map.get(name);
    if (set == null) {
      if (map.putIfAbsent(name, ImmutableSet.of(entry))
        return true
      continue;
    }
    if (set.contains(entry)
      return false; // no need to change, already exists
    Set<String> newSet = ImmutableSet.copyOf(Iterables.concat(set, ImmutableSet.of(entry))        
    if (map.replace(name, set, newSet)
      return true;
  }
}
```

This is now an entirely thread-safe *lock-free* structure, where concurrent readers and writers will not block each other (modulo the lock-freeness of the underlying ConcurrentMap implementation). This implementation does have an O(n) in its write, where your original implementation was O9n) in the read. Again if you are read-mostly rather than write-mostly this could be a big win.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with less coding.
Here is an example, it is part of the concurrency stress test Jcstress
[enter link description here](https://github.com/openjdk/jcstress/blob/master/jcstress-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jcstress/samples/primitives/library/Library_01_CHM.java)

```
void add(String key, String val) {
     List<String> list = map.computeIfAbsent(key,
                    k -> Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>()));
     list.add(val);
}
```